# No results from ES when Input JSON has "_source" fields

Tags: json, elasticsearch, postman

When input JSON has "_source" fields then output JSON has no output for the search.

There is two case.
Case_1: Input JSON does have "_source" fields and Output is Null
Case_2: Input JSON does not have "_source" fields and Output has searched values for the entire fields in ES

The case_1 has **"_source": [" coreid ", " program_id " ],**

```
{
    "_source": [" coreid ", " program_id " ],
       "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": 
                    {
                        "must": [
                            {"match": {"tu_tm": { "query": "tu"   }  } },
                            {"match": {"program_id": {"query": "86328" }  } }
                                ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": 
                    {
                        "must": [
                            {"match": {"tu_tm": {"query": "tu"  }  }  },
                            {"match": {"program_id": {"query": "86330" } } }
                                ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "tu_tm": {
                                        "query": "tu"
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The output has  **"_source": {}**

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1.000008,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "matching_tool",
        "_type": "data",
        "_id": "THcc2msB1g08C8plFbE0",
        "_score": 1.000008,
        "_source": {}
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `_source` definition from

```
"_source": [" coreid ", " program_id " ],
```

to

```
"_source": ["coreid", "program_id" ],
```

Surrounding white spaces for field ids are unnecessary.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it really worked.
Thanks a ton, I could not ignore such things.